# How do I take the corresponding values of a dropdown in Angular Material?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to implement cascading dropdowns in angular using angular material. 
But I am unable to take corresponding values. 
Could anyone please help me with this?

```html
<mat-form-field>
      <mat-select [formControl]="country" placeholder="select" 
      #singleSelect>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let country of countries.Countries"
        [value]="domain">
          {{country.CountryName}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field>
      <mat-select [formControl]="state" 
      placeholder="select" #singleSelect>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let i=0;let state of countries.Countries" 
        [value]="domain">
          {{state.CountryName[i].states.stateName}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field>
      <mat-select [formControl]="city" 
      placeholder="select" #singleSelect>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let i=0;let j=0;let city of countries.Countries" 
        [value]="domain">
          {{city.CountryName[i].states[j].CityName}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field>
      <mat-select [formControl]="municipality"
      placeholder="select" #singleSelect>
        <mat-option 
        *ngFor="let i=0;let j=0;k=0;let 
         municipality of countries.Countries"
         [value]="domain">
          {{municipality.city.CountryName[i].states[j].Cities[k].MunName}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

```json
[
   {
      "Countries":[
         {
            "id":0,
            "CountryName":"Indonesia",
            "States":[
               {
                  "id":0,
                  "StateName":"Bali",
                  "Cities":[
                     {
                        "id":0,
                        "CityName":"Denpasar",
                        "Municipalities":[
                           {
                              "id":0,
                              "MunName":"Mun1"
                           },
                           {
                              "id":1,
                              "MunName":"Mun2"
                           },
                           {
                              "id":2,
                              "MunName":"Mun3"
                           }
                        ]
                     },
                     {
                        "id":1,
                        "CityName":"Kuta",
                        "Municipalities":[
                           {
                              "id":0,
                              "MunName":"Mun4"
                           },
                           {
                              "id":1,
                              "MunName":"Mun5"
                           },
                           {
                              "id":2,
                              "MunName":"Mun6"
                           }
                        ]
                     },
                     {
                        "id":2,
                        "CityName":"Tuban",
                        "Municipalities":[
                           {
                              "id":0,
                              "MunName":"Mun7"
                           },
                           {
                              "id":1,
                              "MunName":"Mun8"
                           },
                           {
                              "id":2,
                              "MunName":"Mun9"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "id":1,
                  "StateName":"Badgis",
                  "Cities":[
                     {
                        "id":0,
                        "CityName":"Denpasar",
                        "Municipalities":[
                           {
                              "id":0,
                              "MunName":"Mun1"
                           },
                           {
                              "id":1,
                              "MunName":"Mun2"
                           },
                           {
                              "id":2,
                              "MunName":"Mun3"
                           }
                        ]
                     },
                     {
                        "id":1,
                        "CityName":"Andarab",
                        "Municipalities":[
                           {
                              "id":0,
                              "MunName":"Mun4"
                           },
                           {
                              "id":1,
                              "MunName":"Mun5"
                           },
                           {
                              "id":2,
                              "MunName":"Mun6"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "id":1,
            "CountryName":"India",
            "States":[
               {
                  "id":0,
                  "StateName":"Delhi",
                  "Cities":[
                     {
                        "id":0,
                        "CityName":"Sonipat",
                        "Municipalities":[
                           {
                              "id":0,
                              "MunName":"Mun1"
                           },
                           {
                              "id":1,
                              "MunName":"Mun2"
                           },
                           {
                              "id":2,
                              "MunName":"Mun3"
                           }
                        ]
                     },
                     {
                        "id":1,
                        "CityName":"Rohtak",
                        "Municipalities":[
                           {
                              "id":0,
                              "MunName":"Mun4"
                           },
                           {
                              "id":1,
                              "MunName":"Mun5"
                           },
                           {
                              "id":2,
                              "MunName":"Mun6"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "id":1,
                  "StateName":"Karnataka",
                  "Cities":[
                     {
                        "id":0,
                        "CityName":"Mangalore",
                        "Municipalities":[
                           {
                              "id":0,
                              "MunName":"Mun1"
                           },
                           {
                              "id":1,
                              "MunName":"Mun2"
                           },
                           {
                              "id":2,
                              "MunName":"Mun3"
                           }
                        ]
                     },
                     {
                        "id":1,
                        "CityName":"Hubli",
                        "Municipalities":[
                           {
                              "id":0,
                              "MunName":"Mun4"
                           },
                           {
                              "id":1,
                              "MunName":"Mun5"
                           },
                           {
                              "id":2,
                              "MunName":"Mun6"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: I would recommend to disable the selects until the previous one is selected. Then storing the country selected and on the next select, use  `let state of country.States`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement a solution where most of the logic is in the component and not in the template, as it is very difficult to understand with all the different loop variables.

The approach I am showing you in [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-skopwn?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) stackblitz here, is one that subscribes to the `valueChanges` property of a `FormControl` and then based on the value selected, filters the values for the next `FormControl`, e.g. `mat-select`.

The dropdowns are displayed based on the values they are displaying. Meaning they won't be shown if the filtered values are not available and thus one dropdown after the other is shown.

This might not be the best or cleanest way to implement this, but it definitely gets the job done.

> Note: I removed the surrounding `[]` from your `countries` object.
>   They are not needed.

Key points from the template: Use `*ngIf` to conditionally display the state, city and municipality inputs (based on the pre-filtered values, see component code).

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [formControl]="country" placeholder="Select Country" #countrySelect>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let country of countries.Countries" [value]="country.CountryName">
            {{country.CountryName}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field *ngIf="statesFiltered && statesFiltered.length">
    <mat-select [formControl]="state" placeholder="Select State" #stateSelect>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let state of statesFiltered" [value]="state.StateName">
            {{state.StateName}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Key points from the component: Use `valueChanges` to listen for changes and filter the values for the next select element to be shown. A bit ugly: Reset the filtered values on each value change to hide the input elements further down the chain.

```
this.country.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
  this.statesFiltered = [];
  this.citiesFiltered = [];
  this.municipalitiesFiltered = [];
  this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  this.statesFiltered = this.countries.Countries.find(country => {
    return country.CountryName === this.country.value;
  }).States;
});
```

Comment: This is perfect.You made my day.Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi, is there any way to search the content in select options in angular material.Can you please help?

Comment: Have a look at the Angular Material [Autocomplete](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete), there is an example with filtering on the examples tab.

Comment: It shows mat-option inside mat-autocomplete but here as we are using mat-select , can you please provide a sample for example.Thanks in advance

Comment: You would have to refactor your code to use an `input` element in combination with `mat-autocomplete`, there are plenty of posts on SO that cover this topic.